# How to use react-color in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Everyone who's used react-color knows it's powerful, but how can I use it in typescript, or do I have a color picker that supports typescript?

Comment: what is the problem that you have encountered?

Comment: looks like there are types in DefinitelyTyped https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-color

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add it's types to your project.

```
npm i @types/react-color
```

or

```
yarn add @types/react-color
```